# Metric induced by a linear combinations of inner products on a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, connections

I have encountered a situation that assigns not just one inner product, but a linear combinations of inner products to each point of a manifold. Specifically, each point x in $X^n$ is assigned:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i \langle \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{u} \rangle_i
$$

for all vectors $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{u}$ at x.

What is the connection and metric that would parallel transport this structure?

Comment: If the $\lambda_i$ are all positive, then  the sun is also an inner product. And has its own Levi-Civita connection and parallel transport. As far as I know, there is no simple relationship of this to the connections of the individual inner products.

Comment: @Deane Yes, the $\lambda_1$ are all positive.

Comment: @Deane Is the metric then $ds^2 = ( \lambda_1 g_{\mu\nu}  + \lambda_2 h_{\mu\nu} + ...) dx^\mu dx^\nu$?

Comment: You should verify this yourself